# S3 month data transfer out beyond the global free tier

Tags: amazon-s3, bandwidth

I have been working on transferring a lot collection of image to amazon S3. I have a bucket policy set to prevent public access to the images and all I'm doing it copying the images from my current host to S3.

I have currently moved 2.8 GB of photos. When I look at my billing it says

I have used 128 GB of month data transfer out beyond the global free tier. How is this possible if all I'm doing is transferring into S3?

How is this calculated? and is there anyway to see the details and or dispute the bandwidth calculation?

[image]

Comment: Did you enable logging on your bucket?

Comment: Are you using any utilities to "mount" S3 onto a computer? They might be creating local copies of the files. I recommend you turn on [Detailed Billing Reports](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports.html) that can assist in analyzing costs -- but only after the reporting option is configured! Also, if you know that the costs are related to a specific Amazon S3 bucket, you can turn on Bucket Logging as suggested by @sqlbot.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein bucket "mount"-emulating utilities is a good question, but it shouldn't result in data transfer "out" charges if the bucket is mounted to an EC2 instance.  It would be in-region (free) or cross-region (cheap) transport.  Also... this cost element is aggregated across all services in the region, isn't it? -- S3, EC2, RDS, anything sending data directly out to the Internet -- not just S3 -- unless that's the only service being used.

Comment: S3 is the only service I'm using at this point. I'm hosting at digital ocean. I just enabled bucket logging and I'll look into turning on detailed billing reports. I'm using Lucee / ColdFusion to [(connect)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSd160b5fdf5100e8f-4439fdac128193edfd6-7f08.html) to my S3 bucket. At some point I was planning on setting up the AWS CLI. Essentially the goal is use S3 for photo backup only, but only if it's cost effective.

Comment: Since you do not yet have the AWS CLI installed, how are you "copying the images from my current host to S3"?

Answer (score 1):

As @Michael-sqlbot  point out, if you use anything outside AWS network(or AWS cross region ) , data traffics is going to cost you dearly. Since you mention Digital Ocean :  if your web apps in Digital ocean access S3 bucket, AWS definitely charging you the data "out" bandwidth.

S3 cheap storage is best for AWS same region data processing.  E.g. launch EC2 instance and do massive processing on multiple GB of s3 data. Similar what you did inside a intranet.

Serving S3 data to outside world is another story, this is similar to typical web hosting : you need to pay for the bandwidth. Anyone that need to serve web request from S3 should subscribe to CDN cache (content delivery network) to avoid the massive s3 bucket internet download cost.

If you just want to save tons of image for occasional retrieval, S3 is not a right place. Instead, you should just use google drive, dropbox,etc.

Comment: Thanks, yes I have been using dropbox as a backup strategy and am rethinking my original S3 plan. S3 just seemed like the cleanest solution. My new site is not live yet, so I'm having a hard time understanding the details on where the bandwidth "out" is coming from, but at this point it's a learning process. Digital ocean added storage blocks that I'm exploring now. My thinking was not to keep all my eggs in one basket and if I wanted to migrate hosts again (which I'm doing - now co-location to cloud) my assets storage wouldn't change.

Comment: @leif : I suggest you shutdown the the cross cloud API  immediately. If you open the content to the internet world, even a simple bot crawling is happily retrieve the data and slap you with more S3 download cost. (well, I haven't mentioned about scary story of DDoS).